# SQL Server: How to increment datetime and use that value to get a column to retrieve the next value?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

Kind of new to TSQL and was hoping someone could help. I have a huge table that has about 1000 columns and about 1700 rows. Each column is a date except for one which is just a name. Every value in the table (except for the name column) is a number. What I want to do is the following:

1. Start at the lowest spectrum for dates for a given row (this lowest date is known to be January 25th, 2011) and store this as the first value.
2. Increase the date by 1, and find the corresponding column for the same given row above. This becomes the second value.
3. Divide the first value by the second value.
4. Store all of this in a new table where the row would be the name, the column would be the date for the first value and the value would be the result of the division performed.

I realize that I would need to mess around with dynamic SQL to do this, but my skills are a bit lacking and I'm having trouble even trying to get a date query set into a variable. (I keep getting that my string is not a valid identifier).

So I'll take this step by step, I can perform a regular select using the date above to get the value of the lowest date for a given row. Can anyone help me increment this date value by 1 and look at that column in the same row to get the second value?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Could you add your table structure for better understand?

Comment: Welcome here. You have to add into your question the code you have tried and from it what is going wrong. **A side note:** a table with 1000 columns ??? This is by far far far far far a really, really, really, really, really bad design. Maybe you could ask for help here on how you could improve this design explaining why you have all that columns in a single table.

Comment: this is not part of the answer of your question but to reduce the complexity of your table with 1000 columns, you could maintain another table for your columns and store data in another table with respect to those column Ids.

Comment: You can increase a date value with the DATEADD() function, but I don't understand the rest of what you're asking at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the comments. I guess the closest I can get to an accepted answer is @JorgeCampos and @VIVEK. The issue was definitely my table size. The original table is over 1 000 000 rows and I thought it might be easier to work on a pivot table which is the one I was asking about. Turns out that working on the original dataset (although slow) is the best way to proceed as the new table was just too crazy to work with.

Glad that there's help out there for someone who was so lost on this issue though. Thanks again fellas!

Comment: If you have performance issues for a table with 1 million rows why don't you post the query and ask for help.

Comment: I just might do that, there are still a few bugs that I want to sort out in the query. Then I'll give optimization a go myself. Hopefully I won't be back, but we'll see...